# STM32 chip specs do not match the datasheet?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, memory

I've recently purchased a couple of STM32L152R8T6 chips from a local electronics shop. 
According to the page 11 of the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00277537.pdf), this chip is supposed to have 10K of SRAM and 64K of FLASH.
However, when I query one of those chips (that I've already soldered onto a perfboard, along with simple transistor UART 3.3v<>5v level shifter) with 'stm32flash', it responds with this:

```
$ stm32flash -b 115200 /dev/ttyACM0 
stm32flash 0.4

http://stm32flash.googlecode.com/

Interface serial_posix: 115200 8E1
Version      : 0x30
Option 1     : 0x00
Option 2     : 0x00
Device ID    : 0x0416 (L1xxx6(8/B))
- RAM        : 16KiB  (2048b reserved by bootloader)
- Flash      : 128KiB (sector size: 16x256)
- Option RAM : 16b
- System RAM : 4KiB
```

And the linker script from STM32L1xx Standard Peripheral Library v1.3.1, for Medium Density devices, sets the size of FLASH to 128K, and the size of RAM to 16K.

**The questions are**:

1. Why memory sizes do not match the ones described in the datasheet?
2. Do I have some dodgy/fake/counterfeit chip?
3. What memory size should I state in the linker script? (that one is probably a bit offtopic).

I've also tried to use it with ST's own Flash Loader Demonstrator (through Windows 7 on VirtualBox VM, don't have it on the actual hardware, maybe I'll test that later), but it keeps saying that it's an "Unrecognized device... Please reset your device then try again".

I use an Arduino Mega 2560 as an USB<>UART bridge, using RX0/TX0 to connect to STM32. Of course, Arduino's AVR chip is disabled by wiring its /RESET to GND.
With such setup, I can easily, without any errors along the way, upload and verify (with stm32flash and a serial port) a simple program to blink a LED, and it will work. I've also played around with integrated DAC and ADCs, they also seem to work just fine (although a bit slower than I expected, but that's probably not related - I'm only starting with ST micros).

I've also stumbled upon this [thread](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=https%3A%2F%2Fmy%2Est%2Ecom%2Fpublic%2FSTe2ecommunities%2Fmcu%2FLists%2Fcortex_mx_stm32%2Fdetect%20sram%20size%20at%20run%20time&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D7580009C4E14902C3CDE46A77F0FFD06506F5B&currentviews=633) that might have an answer to this question, but I don't know if it explains why ST's own tool is not able to see the chip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The device ID of your controller is the following:

```
   Device ID    : 0x0416 (L1xxx6(8/B))
```

and I think the key is this part: **L1xxx6(8/B)**, this ID must be the same for **STM32L152R8** and **STM32L152RB** devices.

If we have a look at ST's table of flash/RAM sizes, the **STM32L152RB** has 128K/16K.

[image]

I am not sure, maybe the SPL can only assign the RB values when this device ID is read.

You can give a try and set the 64K/10K values manually, and check if you can program the MCU.

I do not think that your ICs are fake, check the text on them to make sure it's an **8** and not a **B**.

Comment: I see, I guess that's the case then. I've double-checked the marking on my chip and sure, it has **8** in it. I've tried to set 10K of RAM in the linker script (forgot to change flash size though), and my blinker program seems to work just fine. I guess, since memory sizes grow upwards, this little program won't be affected by that change. However, for some strange reason I still cannot reach this chip with ST Flash Loader Demonstrator at all (I've already tried it with Windows on real hardware). Hm...